# get last modified date of sharepoint group.

Tags: sharepoint-2007

1. How to get last modified date of a sharepoint group.
2. how to get date when a user is added to a sharepoint group.

thanks for your help.

Arvind

Answer (score 3):

You can get the "Creation" and "Last Modified" Date through following Code:

```
SPList groupInformationList = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUserInfoList;

SPListItem grpItem = groupInformationList.Items.GetItemById(group.ID); // Pass the ID of group
// OR, SPListItem grpItem = web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItemById(web.SiteGroups["group_name"].ID);

string groupCreationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(grpItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Created]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"); //Group Creation Date

string groupLastModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(grpItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Modified]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"); // Group Modification Date
```

Comment: Great! Thanks @KunwarAmitesh, I was looking for something exactly like this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of an out of the box way to do this. The [SPGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup_members.aspx) and [SPUserCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spusercollection_members) classes do not contain dates. And even looking in the content database (which is unsupported), neither the Groups or GroupMembership tables have dates.